# How does this JavaScript augmented method work?

Tags: javascript

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229995/basic-augmenting-types-in-javascript), I am following Douglas Crockford's *JavaScript, The Good Parts*. In chapter 4, he talks about augmenting types, which I find very confusing. He writes this sample code:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};

Number.method('integer', function (  ) {
    return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceil' : 'floor'](this);
});
```

He then tests the new `integer` method:

```
document.writeln((-10 / 3).integer());  // -3
```

I don't understand the syntax of `this.prototype[name]` (in particular, the brackets) or `Math[this < 0 ? 'ceiling' : 'floor'](this)` (again, the brackets and also where `Math` came from). More importantly, can someone explain how the code in general works, and why the test code works?

Comment: `obj.foo;` `obj["foo"];` `var foo = "foo"; obj[foo];` All give the same result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By extending `Function.prototype` you add a method available to every function. Remember that functions in JavaScript are objects, and as such they can have properties and methods eg. `call` or `apply`.

The `method` function method lets you add a method to the prototype of any given function. `Number` is a function; the constructor of numbers, which has a `prototype`. Functions that you add to the prototype are available for all instances of the object, in this case a number.

`Math` is a built-in object in JavaScript, by using bracket notation you can dynamically access the property of an object. Remember that object keys are just strings, even if you don't write them as string, they can still be accessed with bracket notation with a string, for example:

```
var obj = {
  key: 'hello'
};

var k = 'key';

obj[k]; //=> 'hello'
```

In the case of `Math` it's simply deciding if it should use `ceil` (not "ceiling") or `floor` based on a condition, you could write like this:

```
if (this < 0) {
  Math.ceil(this);
} else {
  Math.floor(this);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is weird.

In most languages you do `foo = someObject.someMember` and JS allows that too.

But it also lets you do `foo = someObject["someMember"]` which seems silly... until you realize that the string could be replaced with a variable

```
var memberName="someMember"
foo = someObject[memberName]
```

Now you're able to write very dynamic code that can leverage object members without knowing the names of those members when you write the code.  This is what the code you posted is doing.  It feels dirty at first but that feeling will pass ;)